# Does GPU volumetric rendering work with Mac Pro Radeon D700s?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, smoke-simulation, volumetrics

Has anyone successfully rendered smoke (or any volumetric shaders for that matter) with GPU on a Mac Pro with Radeon Firepro D700s?  I saw that smoke/fire is supported on Open CL (as listed here: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/features.html), was curious why I'm still getting the ol' black box when rendering through cycles & GPU.  Is this card just not supported yet?

Working on a 3.5 GHz 6-Core Intel Xeon X5 Mac Pro with the AMD FirePro D700s.

Comment: What version of Blender are you using? That is probably only supported on 2.79 experimental builds.

Comment: I tried running the latest build from https://builder.blender.org/download/ ,  blender-2.78-72c9141a7a5